# Windows updates fail (KB2992611) - "The stub received bad data"

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am trying to install the two updates for KB2992611 manually on some Windows 2008 R2 SP1 servers as they haven't been brought down by Windows updates:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44618

The installs are erroring with the same error on each server:

Windows update "Update for Windows (KB3018238)" could not be installed because of error 2147944183 "The stub received bad data." (Command line: ""C:\windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\addons\Downloads\Windows6.1-KB3018238-x64.msu"        ")

Can anyone help? I've tried looking online but found no hits on the same error message :-S

Comment: According to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5218e5cc-814d-4be4-a811-d4e88b3b7e66/kb2670838-wont-install-and-is-needed-as-prerequisite-for-ie-10?forum=w7itproinstall, please check your update history and see if KB3004394 is installed.  Try uninstalling it, rebooting, and seeing if the issue persists.  There is also an update available to remove KB 3004394 located here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3024777.

Answer (score 1):

We hat a similar issue which was solved via [article (ID: 2028588)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028588/error-1783-the-stub-received-bad-data). Our environment had to much services configured. Once we removed some older monitoring clients the issue went away.